# Facebook api for creating business manager causing Permissions Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am testing facebook business manager API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-manager-api.
I am testing (creating business manager API)
`curl \
-F "name=Pomni Media" \
-F "vertical=ADVERTISING" \
-F "primary_page=<PAGE_ID>" \
-F "timezone_id=1" \
-F "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<USER_ID>/businesses"` with `a test user`.

I added postman
`POST https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/125157388313921/businesses
name : xxxx xxxx
vertical: ADVERTISING
primary_page: 2076479342635006
timezone_id: 1
access_token: EAAcikSwak2oBAI3...
appsecret_proof: 0db84ee1ded55f9ce0ef4a9d91449940014...`

And it's result is
`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "FQmaUMdrdV3"
  }
}`

Permission of above user `125157388313921` is 
      `"user_birthday",
      "user_religion_politics",
      "user_relationships",
      "user_relationship_details",
      ...
      "user_managed_groups",
      "manage_pages",
      "pages_manage_cta",
      "pages_show_list",
      "publish_pages",
      "read_page_mailboxes",
      "ads_management",
      "ads_read",
      "status": "granted"
      "business_management",
      "public_profile"`

Gave all permissions.
And the the facebook app has business manager available level.
[image]

I am working with this issue for 5 days, but not success yet.
Any kind of hint will appreciate!

UPDATE: the test user 125157388313921 was created by this api.
`https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=XXX+XXX&permissions=public_profile,user_friends,email,...,pages_manage_cta,pages_manage_leads,ads_read,ads_management,business_management&method=post&access_token=XXXX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to login at business.facebook.com as test user.
It said that **"You are signed in to Facebook with a test user. Ad Manager is not available with this type of access, To use Business Manager sign in with your personal Facebook account"**, I tried with real user with permission `business_manager` and successed.